# StackOverflow Exception Error in GET, how to solve it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**I am trying to do a validation within a get and I am getting StackOverflow Exception, how to solve it?**

```
public string Origem
{
    get
    {
        switch (this.Origem)
        {
            case "S":
                return "Site";
            case "A":
                return "API";
            default:
                return "Error";
        }
    }
    set
    {
    }
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtT0S.png)

Comment: The getter calls itself recursively.

Comment: You reference `this.Origem` within the the getter for `Origem`.

Comment: You are getting The property value inside itself. `this.Origem` will execute the getter of the same property again causing infinite loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `get` implementation is calling the property itself (see `switch (this.Origem)`). Did you mean to reference a local field instead?

Comment: yes, i need alter when S or A for Site or API

Comment: You need a local field that is updated from the setter and to update the getter to read the same new field.